# How to track billboard background plane to camera?

Tags: camera, tracking

I've got a billboard plane I'm using for a scene background and I have it aligned square to the active camera. I want the billboard to track to the motion of the camera so that when I move and rotate the camera the billboard moves and rotates maintaining its relative position to the camera at all times.

I've tried adding various tracking constraints to the billboard with the camera as target, but nothing is working thus far. Any suggestions? Thanks. Blender 3.2.0, Windows 11

Comment: Did you try using the child of constraint? Or did you try parenting?

Comment: Parent the billboard to the camera! So obvious I missed it. Thank you!

Comment: I posted it as an answer, consider accepting it in case it might help someone else searching ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a *Child Of* constraint or try *Parenting* the billboard to the camera.